# Dockerfile not respecting caching

Tags: python, docker

```
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y python3
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt


CMD ["/app"]
```

This is my dockerfile and according to the documentation, unchanged lines should cache. But I'm seeing some weird behavior where when I don't change my Dockerfile, or add a line at the end, causes a rebuild with no caching. Does anyone have any idea what's happening?

Comment: Your third statement (`COPY . .`) will have to be rerun if any file in the build context has changed. So if you add a newline at the end of the Dockerfile, the `COPY` statement cannot be cached anymore, and the build will have to start from zero

Answer (score 1):

- Using `copy . .` will invalidate the cache for instructions below it every time you make a change to copied files.
- Make sure you have a docker ignore file that stops copying of files you don't need in the container. AND/OR only copy files you need.
- Order your instructions to make changes in the container from least-likely to change to most likely towards the bottom, as much as can be helped.
- You don't need those apt installs

For further reading, check out [Faster or slower: the basics of Docker build caching](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/docker-caching-model/) (and [the whole series](https://pythonspeed.com/docker/), too).

A slightly more optimized version of your dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8

# you would do apt update/install here if you needed it
# python3.8 image includes pip already so no need.

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .
# only copy requirements file here 
# This way, we only need to pip install again when `requirements.txt` changes
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# NOW copy the rest of the files you need

COPY . .
# Even better, specify exact directories/files needed e.g.,
# COPY mypackage .


# now nothing will need to update just because a file changes!

CMD ["/app"]
```